# Can I manipulate the order of mockito matchers?

Tags: mockito, matcher

## Some Context

When setting up mocks (`when`) or verifying calls (`verify`) on mocks, Mockito requires you to either provide all concrete values a mocked method needs, or provide a matcher for all of them. It is not possible to mix these styles.

```java
when(mock.method(1, 2, 3));
when(mock.method(eq(1), eq(2), eq(3)));
```

I am talking about the second style.

Because of the way Mockito works, the order in which matchers are called is important. Internally, Mockito will register the matchers on a stack, executing them in order when necessary.

## What I try to achieve

I want to write some test utilities to be used with mockito. I would like these utility methods to delegate calls to the mock, interjecting some default matchers that would otherwise be boilerplate test code.

For example:

```java
public String callOnMock(int argument2) {
    return mock.call(eq(1), argument2, argThat(i -> i >= 3));
}
```

which would be used like this:

```java
when(callOnMock(eq(2)).thenReturn("result");
```

## The problem

This does not work because Mockito registers these matchers in the wrong order:

1. `eq(2)`
2. `eq(1)`
3. `argThat(i -> i >= 3)`

while it should be

1. `eq(1)`
2. `eq(2)`
3. `argThat(i -> i >= 3)`

**Is there a way for me to manipulate the order that those matchers are registered?**

I now that `org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers` has methods that manipulate the internal stack to allow matchers to be combined (`and`, `or`, `not`) so at least internally inside the Mockito core it is possible.

**Is it also possible to pop and push matchers explicitly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways to achieve the desired behaviour.

## 1. Manipulate the order of matchers on the stack

> **This is not the way to go!**

The `matcherStack` seems to be internal to Mockito.
They do have a method to `pullLocalizedMatchers` from the stack and a `reportMatcher` method to push an `ArgumentMatcher` onto the stack. These could be accessed via

```java
org.mockito.internal.progress.ThreadSafeMockingProgress
    .mockingProgress()
    .getArgumentMatcherStorage()
```

So in theory you could choose this path, but the solution would be brittle because you are messing with the internals of Mockito. They could change without notice in subsequent versions of Mockito.

Luckily there are a couple of alternatives.

## 2. Control the order in which matchers are registered in the first place

Using the Java 8 `Supplier` functional interface (This corresponds to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55297901/426371) given by @ToYonos)

Matchers are registered automatically by Mockito when you call the methods creating them (`eq`, `argThat`, `any`, `isNotNull`, ...). But you can delay calling these methods by passing a `Supplier` for each of those matchers. The convenience method then controls the order in which it executes those suppliers.

```java
public String callOnMock(Supplier<Integer> argument2) {
    return mock.call(eq(1), argument2.get(), argThat(i -> i >= 3));
}

when(callOnMock(() -> eq(2))).thenReturn("result");
```

Using it looks a bit different than the normal Mockito style.

> Special care needs to be taken if you offer convenience methods for those suppliers that use/aggregate other matchers, because of the same problem.
>
> ```java
> callOnMock(() -> AdditionalMatchers.and(isNotNull(), eq(2)))
> ```
>
> will work,
>   but this will not:
>
> ```java
> public Supplier<Integer> and(int matcher1, int matcher2){
>    return () -> AdditionalMatchers.and(matcher1, matcher2);
> }
>
> callOnMock(and(isNotNull(), eq(2)))
> ```

This puts some responsibility with the user of your methods. They have to make sure that none of the matchers gets called accidentally.

## 3. Control the order in which mocks expect matchers

Delegating mock calls to a different mock object can give you control over the order of the arguments.
You will have to define an interface that expects matchers in the order your convenience method receives them, putting the ones added by the convenience method at the end.
Expectations have to be made against that delegate interface.

```java
public interface MockDelegate {
    String call(Integer i1, Integer i0, Integer i2);
}

@Mock
private MockDelegate delegate;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(mock.call(any(), any(), any()))
            .thenAnswer(invocation -> delegate.call(
                    invocation.getArgument(1), // this delegates the call
                    invocation.getArgument(0), // but flips the first two arguments
                    invocation.getArgument(2)
            ));
}

public String callOnMock(int argument2) {
    return delegate.call(argument2, eq(1), argThat(i -> i >= 3));
}
```

This can be used with normal Mockito style matchers:

```java
when(callOnMock(eq(2))).thenReturn("result");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Supplier` :

```
public String callOnMock(Supplier<Integer> argument2) {
    return mock.call(eq(1), argument2.get(), argThat(i -> i >= 3));
}

when(callOnMock(() -> eq(2)).thenReturn("result");
```

Comment: This solution actually works and allows passing nontrivial matchers as well. It does require some effort when using it because building and supplying complex matchers is easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String callOnMock(int argument2) {
    return mock.call(eq(1), eq(argument2), argThat(i -> i >= 3));
}
```

and call it like:

```
when(callOnMock(2)).thenReturn("result");
```

Comment: That only works for the simple example I gave. It's not always possible or desirable to provide the value instead of the matcher.